# arbitrage between currencies

Tags: currencies, arbitrage

looking at the current prices of bitcoins in different currencies it seems as one could buy some in GBP and convert sell them to get USD, than convert those USD back into GBP and make some money. is it that easy? what am i missing? thanks!

Comment: Bank transfers are harder then you might imagine. Often your bank account will get shut down if you make too much money this way. Also fees and taxes and stuff. Other then that, nothing its like free money.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are factoring in taxes and fees charges by the exchanges. Although, if you were to sell on localcoins it would be less expensive to transact in multiple currencies and you save on exchange/broker fees.
But it is basically that easy afaik. Just like any other currency trading (including forex) some currencies are worth more than others at a particular point in time.
***You should also ask yourself if your method of transaction is fast enough to do this kind of trade and make the profit you expected***

That being said, in the last few weeks people Have been buying XBT with USD and selling XBT for CNY at a premium and then converting that CNY to USD and making a nice chunk of change. 
The reason for this is that Chinese citizens have limited access to USD and because most XBT exchanges transact in USD the Chinese can not buy XBT easily. Therefor the chinese pay a premium for their XBT.

What about trying your hand at alt-coin trading on a minimal investment... Say $10 USD. You can learn a lot about these systems of exchange, including where to get XBT cheaper.

XBT = BitCoin

Answer (score 0):

What you are suggesting is called Triangular Arbitrage.
Some info are on the wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_arbitrage

The idea is interesting and if the processus is faster enough it should be without any (or just few) risk.

It would be quite simple to automatize the processus of searching for necessary conditions and suggest to the user how to trade.

In the past I had the same idea and I found some interesting videos about this kind of trade on youtube, but I did not bookmarked them so I cannot link them now. I'll try to find them later.

Comment: Bitdango does exactly that (monitors all markets for triangular arbitrage). https://bitdango.com/marketpairs